# Counterexample on weaker version of result about compact sets

Tags: general-topology, analysis, compactness

The following is a very well known theorem:

Let X be a metric space. $K \subset X$ is compact iff every collection $ \{ F_j \}_{j\in A}$ of closed sets with the finite intersection property in K (that is, if $B \subset A $ is finite then  $\cap\{ F_j \}_{j \in B} \cap K \neq \emptyset$) satisfies $ \cap \{ F_j \}_{j\in A} \cap K \neq \emptyset $.

Does anyone have an example to prove that this result is false if K is not compact, but only closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using $K=[1,\infty)\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and for $j\in\mathbb{N}, F_j=[j,\infty)$

Comment: what will be the contradiction if $x\in \cap_{j=1}^{\infty} F_j$?

Comment: Every finite subcollection has nonempty intersection, but the entire collection of $F_j$s has empty intersection.  (For any $x\in K$, once $j>x$, $x$ won't be in $F_j$.